# Flutter: How to prevent the cursor handle from disappearing?

Tags: flutter, textfield

When trying to position the cursor inside a `TextField`, the cursor handle automatically disappears, and dragging stops. Here's a gif that shows the effect:

[image]

Is there a way to stop this behavior and keep the handle visible (i.e. the dragging active) until the the mouse is released or the finger is removed from the screen?

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    _focusNode.requestFocus();

    return TextField(
      focusNode: _focusNode,
      maxLength: 64,
      expands: false,
      maxLines: 1,
      controller: _textEditController,
      onChanged: _onTextChanged,
      autocorrect: false,
      decoration: new InputDecoration(
        border: new OutlineInputBorder(),
        hintText: "Goal",
        labelText: "Goal",
      ),
    );
}
```

Comment: please try my answer code. please

Comment: have you report this issue to flutter? can i get the link

Comment: Have you managed to solve this issue?

Comment: @kforjan that was quite some time ago, but IIRC, I've used `TextEditController` the wrong way.